# How to return a html string outside of a controller in .net mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using .net MVC 5 to build a web application and trying to implement a method similar to the View() method of the Controller class but only return the evaluated html string.

I have my class Person.cs:

```
public class Person
{
    public string name {get; set;}
    public string address {get; set;}
}
```

And my view template PersonSummary.cshtml:

```
@model Project.Models.Person
<html>
    <h1>Name: @Model.Name</h1>
    <p>Address: @Model.Address</p>
</html>
```

What I want to do is:

```
Person person = new Person(){ name = "foo", address = "bar" };
string myHTML = myNewFunction("PersonSummary", person);
```

I do have a current solution (hack) of creating a seperate controller and getting the string from the ActionResult but after something a little more elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's worth trying to use [RazorEngine](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorEngine/)? It's perfect to use for simple views (as your). It fits perfect f.e. for generating html emails.

Sample methods:

```
public string Compile<T>(string viewContent, T model)
{
    return Razor.Parse(viewContent, model);
}

public string CompileFromPath<T>(string viewPath, T model)
{
    if (!File.FileExists(viewPath))
    {
        return null;
    }

    var viewContent = File.ReadAllText(viewPath, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

    return this.Compile(viewContent, model);
}
```

Usage:

```
var html = CompileFrompath(Server.MapPath("~/my/view/path.cshtml"), person);
```

Remarks:

1. I'm not sure how library handles with iddational helpers for `Html` or `Url`. I belive that it can be configured to handle all desired extensions.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up going for the RazorEngine and just using a string as my view. Unfortunately couldn't get the read from file working on the server so I lost intellisense. Will revisit later, Cheers!

Comment: @user2865446 feel free to post you problem with reading files on server - we can help :)